# Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 722)

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm saving an object as JSON and while trying to read it I get the error in the title.
Is there a function in dart to properly format json data?

Here's the full stack trace

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 722)
...1.25,"tesco":0.95}},"ticked":false}]{"ID":2,"product":{"user":"674971a44...
                                       ^
#0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1383:5)
#1      _ChunkedJsonParser.parse (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:848:48)
#2      _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:35:10)
#3      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:612:36)
#4      JsonCodec.decode (dart:convert/json.dart:216:41)
#5      jsonDecode (dart:convert/json.dart:155:10)
#6      ShoppingListHandler.readShoppingListProducts (package:app/src/handlers/shopping_list_handler.dart:60:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

and here's the json handler class

```dart
class ShoppingListHandler {

  ShoppingListHandler._privateConstructor();

  static final ShoppingListHandler instance = ShoppingListHandler._privateConstructor();

  static File? _file;

  static const _fileName = 'shopping_list_file.txt';

  // Get the data file
  Future<File> get file async {
    if (_file != null) return _file!;

    _file = await _initFile();
    return _file!;
  }

  // Initialize file
  Future<File> _initFile() async {
    final _directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final _path = _directory.path;

    // Check if file exists
    File file = File('$_path/$_fileName');
    if(await file.exists() == false){
      await file.create(recursive: true);
    }

    return file;
  }

  // Users

  static Set<ShoppingListProduct> _shoppingListSet = {};

  Future<void> writeShoppingList(ShoppingListProduct shoppingListProduct) async {
    final File fl = await file;
    _shoppingListSet.add(shoppingListProduct);

    // Now convert the set to a list as the jsonEncoder cannot encode
    // a set but a list.
    final _shoppingListMap = _shoppingListSet.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList();

    await fl.writeAsString(jsonEncode(_shoppingListMap));
  }

  Future<List<ShoppingListProduct>> readShoppingListProducts() async {
    final File fl = await file;
    final _content = await fl.readAsString();

    List<dynamic> _jsonData = [];
    if(_content.isNotEmpty){
      _jsonData = jsonDecode(_content);
    }

    final List<ShoppingListProduct> _shoppingListProducts = _jsonData
        .map(
          (e) => ShoppingListProduct.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>),
    )
        .toList();

    return _shoppingListProducts;
  }

  Future<void> deleteShoppingListProduct(ShoppingListProduct shoppingListProduct) async {
    final File fl = await file;

    _shoppingListSet.removeWhere((e) => e == shoppingListProduct);
    final _shoppingListMap = _shoppingListSet.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList();

    await fl.writeAsString(jsonEncode(_shoppingListMap));
  }

  Future<void> updateShoppingListProduct({
    required int key,
    required ShoppingListProduct updatedShoppingListProduct,
  }) async {
    _shoppingListSet.removeWhere((e) => e.ID == updatedShoppingListProduct.ID);
    await writeShoppingList(updatedShoppingListProduct);
  }

}
```

I take all the objects and put them into json data. Then I can read them and then cast it into a shoppingListProduct object.
Any help will be much appreciated, thank you!

Here's the shoppinglistproduct.txt

```
[{"ID":0,"product":{"user":"674971a44a04ad4fcefe0fdc77d23f63","id":0,"name":"Pepsi Max Cola Bottle","image":"","brandName":"Pepsi","productPrices":{"asda":1.0,"js":1.25,"tesco":0.95}},"ticked":false},{"ID":1,"product":{"user":"674971a44a04ad4fcefe0fdc77d23f63","id":1,"name":"Walkers Wotsits Giants Cheese Snacks 130G","image":"","brandName":"Walkers","productPrices":{"asda":1.0,"js":1.25,"tesco":0.95}},"ticked":false}]{"ID":2,"product":{"user":"674971a44a04ad4fcefe0fdc77d23f63","id":2,"name":"Rowntrees Fruit Pastilles Lollies 4X65ml","image":"","brandName":"Rowntree's","productPrices":{"asda":1.0,"js":1.25,"tesco":0.95}},"ticked":false}]
```

Comment: Could you share the content of `shopping_list_file.txt`?

Comment: The error indicates that it's not proper JSON. It actually indicates where exactly with the `^`. `false}]{"ID":2,"p` this part is not correct JSON. I can't be totally sure without seeing the full JSON but my guess is that a comma is missing so it needs to be `false}],{"ID":2,"p`

Comment: @IvoBeckers I've updated the post with the JSON data

Comment: There's two `]` in there. The first one needs to be a comma.

Comment: https://jsonlint.com/ is a useful website to check if your JSON is correct